# Wsus Downstream servers not shown in upstream

Tags: windows-server-2003, wsus

I have 22 downstream servers and i can see only 2 on the upstream.

and some time the downstream server shown is changed but still only 2

Comment: Eddy can you be specific?<br/>Have you used the same licence for >1 server? I noticed WSUS will only register 1 server even when multiple machines are using the same key.

Comment: you mean the win 2003 server licence ?

Comment: In my case it they were 2008, but I used the same licence twice while I was building the second. When I added the second to WSUS it removed the other server with the same licence.

Comment: well i have 2003,but in your case did you have a workaround ?

Comment: run wuauclt /detectnow on the server; re-add the server to the correct WSUS group; re-run wuauclt /detectnow on the server to install updates; repeat on next server. Or get a legitimate licence

Comment: didn't work also

Answer (score 4):

When a client or downstream server contacts WSUS, it uses the SusClientId and SusClientIdValidation registry keys located in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate` to identify itself. If you've cloned your downstream servers, a normal SysPrep will not reset these values. If more than one client or downstream server has the same SusClientId, they will just overwrite each other each time they update with WSUS.

Deleting these two keys on your downstream servers then rebooting should fix the problem.

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\SusClientId`
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\SusClientIdValidation`

Comment: I tried it but when i synchronize it one server replace another

Comment: this didn't work for my server 2016 wsus installation. However, resetting the id in the db below worked as a charm!

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this same problem on my cloned downstream servers. The GUID for replica downstream servers is held in the database.

Install SSMS locally on the downstream server and connect to the WSUS database.

Run this SQL:

```
update [SUSDB].[dbo].[tbConfigurationA] set serverid=newid()
```

Start the sync on the downstream server again - pretty much immediately, you'll see it populate on the upstream.

Note: If you do this on all downstream servers, you'll be left with a legacy duplicate server as nothing will own the original GUID. You should be able to just delete this - identify which one it is by the sync datetime.