# WSUS Upstream server is not showing current downstream server status

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, windows-update

I've upstream WSUS server running Windows Server 2008 R2 with WSUS 3.2.7600.262. The majority of downstream servers was running OS and WSUS with same versions. Now I migrated some downstream servers to Windows Server 2012 R2 and its embedded WSUS 6.3.9600.16384. And a few of them are not rolling up update and computer status to upstream server, while update approvals are synchronized and installed to computers.

All computers are reporting to downstream server current status. These computers are missing in All computers view on upstream server. If I look to Downstream servers on upstream server, there is displayed 0% Installed/Not Applicable Percentage at line with the downstream server.

I tried to follow one howto with similar problem ([Wsus Downstream servers not shown in upstream](https://serverfault.com/questions/253071/wsus-downstream-servers-not-shown-in-upstream)) but the problem is different and it doesn't help.

It's strange that one of migrated downstream servers with Windows Server 2012 R2 works, and others doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that it needed to do postinstall procedure (new in Windows Server 2012).

```
'C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools\wsusutil.exe' postinstall
```

All steps are at: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852349.aspx

Then the problem is resolved.